# C# newbie - if inside if which is inside another if and so on & try-catch inside try-catch which is inside another try-catch

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Would you excuse a newbie to C# @ Windows Phone development, I'm starting this because I want to write a weather app for my Windows Phone, hope that wouldn't be a stupid reason.
Also apologize for my poor English.

Mostly speaking, my code is copy & paste from the internet, I also find a lot of help from Stackoverflow, I own you a thanks!

So far, my code runs just fine, I just have some newbie questions regarding the code structure or coding behavior, or something else.

You can see the part of my code as following (you can ignore the detail, but only care about the if and try-catch blocks):

```
StreamReader LastReader = null;
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("UpdateAllDay"))
{
    try
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UpdateAllDay"].ToString() == "false")
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("UpdateStartTime") && IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("UpdateEndTime"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (DateTime.Now > Convert.ToDateTime(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UpdateStartTime"].ToString()) && DateTime.Now < Convert.ToDateTime(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UpdateEndTime"].ToString()))
                        {
                            IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("UpdateRate") && isoFile.FileExists("LastUpdateTime.txt"))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    LastReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LastUpdateTime.txt", FileMode.Open, isoFile));                                                    
                                    if ((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(LastReader.ReadLine())).TotalSeconds >Convert.ToInt32(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UpdateRate"].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        LastReader.Close();
                                        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("CityID"))
                                        {
                                            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                                            string url = "http://m.weather.com.cn/data/{0}.html";
                                            string baseUrl = string.Format(url, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CityID"].ToString());
                                            try
                                            {
                                                string WeatherResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);

                                                if (WeatherResult != null)
                                                {
                                                    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("WeatherResult.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile));
                                                    Writer.WriteLine(WeatherResult);
                                                    Writer.Close();

                                                    RootWeatherCore apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootWeatherCore>(WeatherResult);
                                                    await GetData(apiData);

                                                    StreamWriter LastUpdateTime_Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LastUpdateTime.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile));
                                                    LastUpdateTime_Writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                                                    LastUpdateTime_Writer.Close();

                                                    return "true";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
                            }
                        }
                        return "1";
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("UpdateRate") && isoFile.FileExists("LastUpdateTime.txt"))
            {
                try
                {
                    LastReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LastUpdateTime.txt", FileMode.Open, isoFile));
                    if ((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(LastReader.ReadLine())).TotalSeconds > Convert.ToInt32(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UpdateRate"].ToString()))
                    {
                        LastReader.Close();
                        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("CityID"))
                        {
                            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                            string url = "http://m.weather.com.cn/data/{0}.html";
                            string baseUrl = string.Format(url, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CityID"].ToString());
                            try
                            {
                                string WeatherResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);

                                if (WeatherResult != null)
                                {
                                    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("WeatherResult.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile));
                                    Writer.WriteLine(WeatherResult);
                                    Writer.Close();

                                    RootWeatherCore apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootWeatherCore>(WeatherResult);
                                    await GetData(apiData);

                                    StreamWriter LastUpdateTime_Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LastUpdateTime.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile));
                                    LastUpdateTime_Writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                                    LastUpdateTime_Writer.Close();

                                    return "true";
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
            }
            return "1";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { return "1"; }
}
```

Would it scare you? Actually I was scared when I wrote this out. It looks kind of urgly or poorly structured, isn't it?
So, my question is, is it a good practice or behavior to use too much loop of if block inside another if block, and try-catch block inside another try-catch block?

I have so many if block because I think the app would function differently under different conditions.
And I use try-catch a lot because I need to handle with the Isolated Storage in Windows Phone environment, which is suggested by many guru from Stackoverflow and also other website.

Is this a normal coding structure or behavior? Then I should get used to it.
Or is there a better method that I am not aware of?

Or would it be a good idea to use a single & "big" try-catch to put all the code inside it? (If I don't care what's the exact exceptions)

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I didn't even read what the code does, but just looked at the outline. It's most definitely not normal. Why do you need to put these things in try catch blocks?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Especially since each catch block does the same thing (return 1).

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thanks for the comment, I use try-catch each time I handle with the Isolated Storage, is this a good behavior?

Comment: now that is called horrible coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That structure definitely looks overly complex. The only reason that I  could think that you would have so many nested `try...catch` blocks is that you think certain operations may fail for a particular reason.

The problem with doing the handling that way is that comes in on how and when you want to handle the exception in one of the nested catches.

If this is the case you can have multiple `catch` statements for a single `try`.

Something like this:

```
try
{
 //Do Something
}
catch(<ExceptionType1> e1) {}
catch(<ExcetionType2> e2){}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Or if you do not care about the exception you can simply have a general catch that catches all

```
try
{
 //Do Something
}
catch {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I can go with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

for starters, having try blocks inside each other doesn't do anything as they don't catch different exceptions. 
also your catch blocks returns 1. and functions end when they hit a return function. so all ur try/catch is equivalent to a big catch block.

In general  its a good idea to avoid so many nested if's. I'm not familiar with windows phone programming, but a good object oriented solution is to write a function like this

```
boolean isCorrectCondition(ApplicationSetting as)
{
    return condition1 && condition2 && ... && last condition;
}
```

and instead of ur monstrous nest of if statements have something like

```
if(isCorrectCondition(as)) {
// do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that looks promising, I'll have a try.